# C# linq dates between

Tags: linq, date, between

I am tring to get a list of dates from my db that will eventually be used to populate a calendar. Each 'calendar event' has a start date & end date, i need to get all dates between & including the start & end date.

i am stuck on the WHERE statement, as i am not sure what to use for this

```
public List<EventFeed> GetCalendarDates()
    {

        return (from eventsList in GetEventsList()      
                select new EventFeed()
                        {
                          //EventDate = todo
                        }).ToList();
    }
```

UPDATE

just to be clear, if i have a calendar event called foobar which starts on 22/08/2010 and ends on 24/08/2010, then i want my list return:

22/08/2010,
23/08/2010,
24/08/2010

thanks
kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar recently, I used a `Func<>` to extract the dates from the range and used the result in the linq query.

I have added the same `Func` to your Linq query below. You didn't specify the name of the object that is returned by `GetEventsList()` so just replace the `EventItem` type for the first type parameter in the Func<> with whatever type you need.

```
public static List<EventFeed> GetCalendarDates()
{
    Func<EventItem, List<DateTime>> extractEventDates = eventItem =>
                                                          {
                                                              var dates = new List<DateTime>();
                                                              for (var date = eventItem.StartDate;
                                                                   date <= eventItem.EndDate;
                                                                   date = date.AddDays(1))
                                                              {
                                                                  dates.Add(date);
                                                              }
                                                              return dates;
                                                          };

    return (from eventItem in GetEventsList()
            from eventDate in extractEventDates(eventItem)
            select new EventFeed
                       {
                           EventDate = eventDate
                       }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: thanks fletcher, i came up with something similiar, but your solution is less code, thanks kb

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to select all the events that started on or after start date and ended on or before end date!

If yes, then this will help

```
var query = from @event in events
                        where @event.Start.Date >= startDate.Date
                              && @event.End.Date <= endDate.Date
                        select @event;
```

Comment: Hi mho, thanks for your reply, but where does this come from?

@event.Start.Date